# IIS Server Farm

Tags: iis-6

I've got 2 Server 2003 boxes that need to be put into a server farm.  While I can handle setting up the cluster, I need help keeping the content files synced.  The client has a habit of fiddling with html files, so I know they'll end up out of sync at some point.  What are my options for keeping them synced?

Answer (score 1):

[Windows DFS](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2003/technologies/storage/dfs/default.mspx) works pretty well for this scenario - but you probably will want to be on Windows 2003 R2.

Comment: Would there be a performance hit involved in this?  Does it require that I'm on domain?

Comment: It does require an AD domain to operate. I have never personally seen a performance hit while using it, but one anecdote is probably not a good thing to base your decision on.

Answer (score 0):

Set up an FTP (or better yet, SFTP or SCP) server that is separate from the web servers. Set up an automatic job to [sync](http://www.aboutmyip.com/AboutMyXApp/DeltaCopy.jsp) the files in the FTP server to their rightful place in the web server cluster every few minutes. Then the FTP server is the canonical source, and the web servers are its slaves.

It's probably also a good idea to remove any FTP servers on the web cluster.